# Redis: How to use COUNT on sorted sets with zscan command

Tags: redis

I'm trying to get x records from sorted sets, but unfortunatelly it returns me all records.

Example:

```
> zadd example 1 x:1
(integer) 1
> zadd example 2 x:2
(integer) 1
> zadd example 3 x:3
(integer) 1
> zadd example 4 x:4
(integer) 1
> zadd example 5 x:5
(integer) 1
```

Now, when I do:

```
> zscan example 0 MATCH x* COUNT 2
```

I get:

```
1) "0"
2) 1) "x:1"
2) 1.0
3) "x:2"
4) 2.0
5) "x:3"
6) 3.0
7) "x:4"
8) 4.0
9) "x:5"
10) 5.0
```

I found in documentation:

> When iterating Sets encoded as intsets (small sets composed of just
>   integers), or Hashes and Sorted Sets encoded as ziplists (small hashes
>   and sets composed of small individual values), usually all the
>   elements are returned in the first SCAN call regardless of the COUNT
>   value.

I tried to change score of element from 1 (integer) to values like: 1.00001, 1.00002... or 100001, 100002. But looks like it doesn't work that way.

Any idea how can I use COUNT paramater in ZSCAN with sorted sets?

Comment: The same documentation (http://redis.io/commands/scan) also state that: "This is **just an hint** for the implementation", hence you shouldn't count on `COUNT`

Comment: Can you not achieve what you want using `ZRANGE`? http://redis.io/commands/zrange